# Writing Single SQL Query for calculating count of multiple boolean columns with "True" condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can  write multiple counts in one SQL query.

For example instead of all the queries below,i want all counters for boolean features in one single query.

```
select count(feature1) from my_table where feature1 = True
select count(feature2) from my_table where feature2 = True
select count(feature3) from my_table where feature3 = True
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type, nor can you specify a `true` value. Most databases don't have a boolean type either. What is the *actual* type of `feature1`? If it's a numeric type with `1` for true, like `bit`, you could just calculate all sums at the same time

Answer (score 3):

use conditional aggregation like below

```
select 
sum(case when feature1= 'True'  then 1 else 0 end), 
sum(case when feature2= 'True'  then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when feature3= 'True'  then 1 else 0 end) 
from my_table
```